# Only in IE after the second click the following JavaScript is not working (There are no issues in other browsers)

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, model-view-controller

```
$(document).ready(function () {               
   $("#applyVoucherBtn").click(function () {
        var code = $("#voucherCode").val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("ShoppingCart", "Payment")';
        if (code != '') {
            validateAndClaimVoucher(code, url);
        } else {
            $("#voucherErrorMessage").html('@LocalizationService.GetRawString("Payment.ShoppingCart.VoucherCanNotEmpty")');
        }
    });
 });
```

The following code segment is not getting called when I click the button second time on wards only in IE. Other browsers do not have any issues.

The button is declared as follows

```
<button id="applyVoucherBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
          @Html.Raw(LocalizationService.GetString("Payment.ShoppingCart.ApplyVoucher"))
</button>
```

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Do you see any warnings or errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @YogeshHShenoy I'm using IE 11.1593.14393.0

Comment: @KenY-N No I don't see any errors

Comment: How does it not work? `click` not called? `code` is blank? `validateAndClaimVoucher()` fails?

Comment: @KenY-N whet does the function validateAndClaimVoucher() do. Are you getting error in that function?